# For a mysql procedure, Do I need to specify INTO to display the results?

Tags: mysql

Do I need to specify the `INTO` parameter for every column I want sent out of the procedure?

If I have the following:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
table
WHERE
col1 = 'something'
```

Do I need to specify INTO for each column?

Comment: Yes, it works with the INTO keyword as well as without, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , see example

```
 BEGIN 

    SELECT password                      , 
           active_flg                    , 
           lastname                      , 
           firstname                     , 
           gender_code                   , 
           birth_dttm                    
    INTO   p_password                      , 
           p_active_flg                    , 
           p_lastname                      , 
           p_firstname                     , 
           p_gender_code                   , 
           p_birth_dttm                    
    FROM   students
    WHERE  student_id = p_student_id ; 

END
```

take from link :
http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_SELECT.php

Comment: Thank you sir.. This was what I needed to know.. :)  I was unclear if INTO was only used when calculations or other operations  were needed but I can see that INTO is always used.

Comment: One more question.. Do I need to specify OUT?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it answeres my last question as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you are trying to achieve.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testproc ()
BEGIN
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
table
WHERE
col1 = 'something'
END;
```

Will return results similar to SELECTing a table, you can get multiple rows, returned.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testproc (OUT col1 INT, OUT col2 VARCHAR(255), OUT col3 INT, OUT col4 INT)
BEGIN
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 INTO col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
table
WHERE
col1 = 'something'
END;
```

Can ONLY return 1 row, and you call it like so
CALL testproc(@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4);
nothing is returned visable, though the variables are set, these variables can be used in other queries or just called together
SELECT @col1, @col2, @col3, @col4;
OR

SELECT blah from othertable where col2=@col2;

Your stored procedure can also contain multiple selects where it uses those variables internally for inputs into new selects, with IF THENs etc, etc.